# Bazel Sync failed. Error: Deriving targets from project directories failed

Tags: bazel, mediapipe

I try to run the mediapipe with Bazel in Android Studio. However, I have an issue with the bazel processing failed. The error state is 'deriving targets from project directories failed'.

The reference I follow: https://margaretmz.medium.com/hello-mediapipe-on-android-813fc0553d79

[link of screenshot about bazel problem met in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIeyi.png)

my version:
bazel: 4.0
android studio: 3.5
windows: 10

Answer (score 0):

In the **.bazelproject** file under **.aswb** folder,
set `derive_targets_from_directories` to false.

then specify the target you need using `targets:`

[image: See here]